# Angular display ngFor value in another tag

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, ngmodel

I have list of comapnies which I display like that:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <select ngModel="selectedCompany" style="width:400px;">
               <option *ngFor="let x of mycompanylist"  value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}
               </option>
            </select>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="CompanyID" value = "{{selectedCompany}}"> 
         </div>
```

I need the value of selected option to be displayed in input tag. I tried to do it with ngModel but it doesnt work.

The main purpose is to pass the value to formControlName so after form is submitted I can recieve the value but if I do it like this:

```
<option *ngFor="let x of mycompanylist"  value="{{x.id}}" fromControlName="ComapnyID">
```

the options are no longer displayed

### UPDATE

I fixed it using `[(ngModel)]` and getting rid of `formControlName`.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-value-populate-in-text-input?file=src/app/app.component.html) for ref.

### UPDATE

Form:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany">
            <option *ngFor="let x of mycompanylist"  [value]="x.id">{{x.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>

      <form [formGroup]="invoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" #formDir="ngForm" novalidate>  
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="control-label col-md-12" for="name">CompanyID</label>  

         <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="CompanyID" value ="{{selectedCompany}}">
         </div>

         <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="invoiceForm.hasError('required', 'CompanyID') && formDir.submitted">  
         CompanyID is required.  
         </span> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label class=" control-label col-md-12" for="description">VendorID</label>  
         <div class="col-md-4"> <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="VendorID"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> <button class="btn" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button> </div>
      </form>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: @SiddAjmera thank you for help but there is one issue. The input field recognizes only the user input, I mean if user types Company 2 and after that chooses Company 3 in options, Company 3 is displayed in input field but the value of input is still Company 2. How can I fix this?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I've added the full form maybe it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution could be sharing the same model

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" style="width:400px;">
    <option *ngFor="let x of mycompanylist"  [value]="x.name">{{x.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"> 
</div>
```

So if the user typing in the field also update the model of the select.

Another solution could be to use **[ngModelChange](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" style="width:400px;" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedCompany($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let x of mycompanylist"  [value]="x.name">{{x.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="company" readonly> 
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  selectedCompany: string = null;
  company: string = null;

  mycompanylist = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Company 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Company 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Company 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Company 4' }
  ];


  onSelectedCompany(company: string) {  
    this.company = company;
  }
}
```

Important to highlight the read-only attribute so that the user can not enter anything

Comment: if I make input field disabled or readonly the value of invoiceForm.value.CompanyID remains null regardless to the values we pass in input threw the ngModel. The input is only showing the value so that I can't send it to my api. I've added error and full form

Comment: Could you put the example of your form in plunker?

Comment: I am not familiar with this so it can take some time.